# Segments up to heap in /proc/self/maps output

Tags: c, operating-system, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

My program, at a certain point in its execution, reads its own /proc/self/maps line by line until (and including) the heap.  The program's path is "/home/t4".  Here is the output:

```
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 68:06 21629911 /home/t4
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 68:06 21629911 /home/t4
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 68:06 21629911 /home/t4
00604000-00608000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
01905000-01926000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap]
```

I was expecting only four segments:  code, constants, static variables, heap; but here, there are five.  The first one clearly must be code, and the last is the heap.  Perhaps the second one is constants--but then what are the other two?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

initialised static variables is followed by uninitialised static variables (.BSS) - which do not need storage in the binary.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why I would not be able to call mprotect to set the (already-mapped) initialized static variables segment to read-only? I get a segfault when I do this, whereas I can make the uninitialized static variables and heap segments read-only without any segfault.

Comment: depends what's in there.  if there's something that immediately gets modified by your program, then of course there's a segfault.  For example, the .got global offset table, used in linking.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the executable part itself (due to the x bit), the second is likely `.rodata` (absence of w bit), the third is everything else (`.bss` and `.data`). The fourth is the result of some `mmap` call using `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. Note that `malloc`(3) may very well be implemented using `mmap`(2) rather than `sbrk`(2). The `[heap]` object there is the classic sbrk-heap (and only that), and does not cover private writable regions obtained using mmap. Traditional stack would be listed as `[stack]`, but stacks of subthreads can use any memory region to store their stack, usually something malloc'd, so you will not see multiple `[stack]`s either...

Confusion complete? :-)

Comment: The fourth one is actually likely to be `.bss`, since the `.bss` segment doesn't take up any space in the binary and so can't be mapped from there.